# is it possible to develop pass creator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

i investigate development for Apple Passbook. i've found that if you have something to perform as a pass to your subscribers, you should create special .pkpass files and distribute them variously. But is it possible to create your own passes in iOS application and add them to Passbook? For example, i have barcode, all additional info, so i want application user to configure his own pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly technically possible to develop your own pass creation App, however to create a .pkpass bundle entirely within an App would require you to embed your Pass ID Private Key within the App which presents a huge security risk.

In practice, your App should send the pass data to your web server which should compile the [.pkpass bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html) and transfer the bundle back to your App to add to Passbook.

The Apple [Pass Kit Framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012158) gives you everything you need to accept a pass from your web server that contains info that your user has provided to your App.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately in Russia nobody uses Passbook, but e-tickets are widely.

Comment: Aeroflot and Transero both support Passbook, as do a number of other prominent Russian companies many of whom use [our service](http://passkit.com) to provide the .pkpass bundles to their Apps or web site.

Comment: Look at my post below, please